# Play! Framework - Multiple MongoDB for same application

Tags: mongodb, playframework, playframework-1.x, morphia

I have to use two MongoDB databases in my Play framework 1.x application; Also I'm using PlayMorphia to connect database.

Currently I am able to connect with only one database by using Morphia plugin.

Can someone suggest me on how to connect with the second MongoDB database.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, Now I am using Morphia Query to access first MongoDB and Normal mongo query to access second MongoDB.